# passing and returning matrix to and from a function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a c++ program that sends a 1D array to a function. The function manipulates the array and returns another array of same order. 
The code is as follows. I am having trouble compiling it. Please help me troubleshoot the errors.
Thanks #include

```
#include <ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
long double * gradiv(long double *,int,long double);

int main ()
{
    int NN=3,c;
    long double *pp;
    long double hx;
    long double matt[NN+2]={10,9,30,63,50};
    pp = gradiv(matt,NN,1.0);
    for (c=0;c<NN+1;c++)
        cout<<endl<< *(pp+c)<<endl;
    return 0;
}


long double *gradiv(long double *matt,int NN,long double hx )
{
    int i,sg1,sg2;
    long double retmat[(NN+2)];
    retmat[0]=0;retmat[1]=0;retmat[NN]=0;retmat[NN+1]=0;
    for (i =2; i <=(NN-1); i++)
    {
            if (i==2){
                sg1=0;
                sg2=1;
                }
            else if (i==(NN-1)){
                sg1=1;
                sg2=0;  
                }
            else{
                sg1=1;
                sg2=1;
                }
        //===== my main formula for gradient(modified due to complication in the boundary)========
            retmat[i]=((*(matt+i)-*(matt+i-1))/hx+(*(matt+i+1)-*(matt+i))/hx)/(sg1+sg2);
            //cout <<retmat[i]<<endl;
        //========================================================================================
    }
return retmat;
}
```

the error message is

```
saurav@sg:~/Desktop/project$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘long double* gradiv(long double*, int, long double)’:
test.cpp:23:14: warning: address of local variable ‘retmat’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  long double retmat[(NN+2)];
```

Comment: For a start `std::arrray` may be worth investigating. Also ask a specific question and not something that is vague

Comment: where should std:: array be added? I am new to c++

The specific question is that, i want the value of array "retmat" to be returned by the function whenever it is called. But it is not happening so.

Comment: Please google it. Also look up `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an address into a local variable `long double retmat[(NN+2)];`. It becomes invalid after the function has executed. You can fix this by allocating the memory for it with `new`:

```
long double* retmat = new long double[(NN+2)];
```

Or use `std::vector` or some other container with managed memory. If you allocate the memory with `new[]`, you must later release it with `delete[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is solved. I compiled the code and the output is correct.

Regarding `delete[]` can you share a little more information to me. My program will be really huge and i might face the problem of memory.

Where in the program should I place `delete[]`

Comment: @user3057202 - The trick in life is to make it easy. Avoid direct use of new/delete. Instead use `std::vector` etc. There is a large body of code/templates to help you.

Comment: @user3057202 - The most optimal solution is to use `std::vector` etc. instead of new and delete but that would require a lot of changes. Using new and delete you should place the delete[] after the last use site of the result and that depends entirely of the rest of your program that you didn't post.

Comment: I modified the code according to the suggestion. Now i have a problem. The program gets compiled but i receive "segmentation fault(core dumped error)"

Kindly view my code and please find the error... I have posted the new program on another comment